How to use AWS QLDB single ledger for different groups
I am planning to use QLDB as registries of data integrity and verifiability.
If I have 1 journal, and I am planning to use the journal for different groups, in which each group has its members.
Let say, I will have 2 groups:
•   Group 1: Financial services with 10 members
•   Group 2: Supply chain with 15 members
How can I identify each group and its members when I want to export to S3 storage, where I can sort and store transactions into each corresponding group. So, I can use it for further data queries, etc.
Thanks & regards,
Prajit
